# Prove that $(T,+,\cdot)$ is a vector space and find its dimension and one basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $T$ is the set of all $(a,b,c)$ such that the system 
\begin{cases}
3x+2y+z=a\\[3px]
x+y+4z=b\\[3px]
5x+2y-2z=c
\end{cases}
is consistent. Prove that $(T,+,\cdot)$ is a vector space and find its dimension and one basis.

Is it enough to only check all conditions for vector space?
How to use the consistent condition of a system?

Comment: Assuming that the first $c$ in your equation system is a typo for $z$, note that the "system is consistent" formulation is just a somewhat backwards way of saying $$T=\left\{\left. x\begin{pmatrix}3\\1\\5\end{pmatrix} + y\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\2\end{pmatrix} + z\begin{pmatrix}1\\4\\-2\end{pmatrix} \right| x,y,z\in\mathbb R\right\}$$ in other words $T$ is the span of those three vectors.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 2 &1 \\ 1&  1&4 \\  5& 2 & -2 \end{bmatrix} \vec{x}= \begin {bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix}$$

The matrix is invertible, so it seems all of $\mathbb{R}^3$ will work for availability of a consistent solution, so this is your $\bf{T}$. $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a vector space of dimension three, and you can use the standard basis for this.

Answer (score 0):

When you row reduce such a system you'll get an augmented matrix that looks something like:
$$\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&\cdots&\cdots&e_1\\0&1&\cdots&e_2\\0&0&1&e_3\end{array}
~~\text{ or}~~~
\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&\cdots&\cdots&e_1\\0&1&\cdots&e_2\\0&0&0&e_3\end{array}
~~\text{ or}~~~
\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&\cdots&\cdots&e_1\\0&0&0&e_2\\0&0&0&e_3\end{array}
$$
where $e_1,e_2,e_3$ are linear expressions in $a,b,c$.

In the case of the first matrix, there is no (explicit) consistency constraint: the solution space for $(a,b,c)$ is all of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

In the second case, the expression $e_3$ has to be $0$ for the system to be consistent. The $(a,b,c)$ that satisfy $e_3=0$ are your solution space $T$.

In the third case, the expressions $e_2$ and $e_3$ both have to be $0$ for the system to be consistent. The $(a,b,c)$ that satisfy $e_2=0$ and $e_3=0$ are your solution space $T$.

To prove that $T$, you don't need to demonstrate that $T$ obeys all the vector space axioms. Since $T \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ is already a vector space, you just have to apply the **subspace test**:

- Show $T$ is non-empty (e.g. show $\mathbf{0} \in T$).
- Show $T$ is closed under vector addition, i.e. if $(a_1,b_1,c_1),(a_2,b_2,c_2) \in T$ are both solutions then their sum is also a solution.
- Show $T$ is closed under scalar multiplication, i.e. if $(a_1,b_1,c_1) \in T$ is a solution and $k\in \mathbb{R}$ then $k(a_1,b_1,c_1)$ is also a solution.